# Returning more than one variable using c functions

Tags: c, function, return

I'm trying to use structure to return more than one variable using following code.

Is there a better way to do this?

and what about this technique, is it efficient?

PS: I'm new to embedded system so trying to discover best techniques for memory , performance and such constrains.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct two func(int , int );

struct two {
    int x;
    int y;

};

int main()  {
    printf("values is\n %i\n %i\n ",func(33,44).x,func(33,44).y);
    return 0;
}


struct two func(int x, int y ) {

    struct two ex;
    ex.x=x;
    ex.y=y;

    return ex;
};
```

Comment: efficient? compared to what?

Comment: From the point of readability, I'd say, use separate functions as getter/setter.

Comment: Indent your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fine technique, and not inefficient.  (But there are also alternatives; one is mentioned in Sean K's answer.  See also http://c-faq.com/misc/multretval.html .)

What's inefficient -- and possibly buggy, if the function has side effects -- is to call it twice in order to get its two values.  I'd use

```
struct two r = func(33, 44);
printf("values are %i %i\n", r.x, r.y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pointers

void Func(int* return1, int* return2)

when calling:
int x, y;
Func(&x, &y);

It is also a common standard to only use the function return value for error codes, and only return values via pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> A function is a relation between a set of inputs and a set of permissible outputs with the property that each input is related to **exactly one output**.

--[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics))

So regarding to the definition of a function, there is no possibility to return more than one value from function.

You can overcome it by returning a structure which contains two values or an array, but you can't return multiple values.

Comment: That's the *mathematical* definition.  But plenty of programming languages explicitly support returning multiple values. (I suppose if you want to be pedantic you can say that they return one value, which is a tuple of several values, but that seems to me like unhelpful hair-splitting.)

Comment: @SteveSummit it's definitely returning a tuple. Maybe some autoboxing is provided however it's still a single return value or not a function. Function returns a single value.

Comment: @SteveSummit in programming we base on mathematics rather then on philosophy. If you are pedantic on design patterns, why wouldn't you on such basics? I have also explained the mechanism of returning *multiple values* in C, so I still don't understand your downvote. You might not be pedantic, but the fact that someone is doesn't qualify him for a downvote.